# Animation classes VS Canvas drawing

Tags: android

I always wonder, when would you use Animation classes VS using Canvas (and loading bitmaps..etc by code)?

Is there a rule of thumb or is the specific advantage/disadvantages? I always  go by animations as  I find it its all ready made and easier but I am not sure if I am missing out on advantaes

Thanks

Comment: extending Animation class saves your tine in creating animation time frames (Handlers, Runnables etc) but. still you can use it with Canvas drawing

Comment: Hmmm. Any links to how to extend animation? I usually just use the class directly

Comment: just extend Animation class by overriding applyTransformation method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to understand the difference between the role of a View and a the role of an Animation.  A view is meant to capture a snapshot of some data and render it.  Sure, the data can change rapidly and the view might frequently need to re-draw, but once the draw is complete, the view's state should be valid until it's data or state is changed.

An Animation is a method by which you define a set of linking, or progressive, changes that should be made to a view to get from a begin state to an end state.  On top of this, there are different types of animations.  You can have an animation where you simply draw one bitmap at a time from a set in quick succession, as you suggest.  You can also have an animation that changes a property of a view over time to get a dynamic effect.

**Edit**

So to answer your question, you should probably just animate the translation property on your ImageView if you want to "slide a view around".

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I think I miss worded maybe my question or simply my lack of understanding. My question, if you have am image that you want want to  move around. Would you use translate animation or would you use draw method and paint and canvas.. Etc?

Comment: @Snake see edit.  It still seems like you're misunderstanding slightly though.  The only scenario you really want to be animating onto a canvas yourself is if you have a draw loop or if you need to do something a simple view can't do.  Otherwise your view hierarchy *is* your draw loop.

Answer (score 0):

Usual animations are for `View` 
`Canvas` is for messive use like games which require Hardware with `Surfaceview` class. 
At least from the view of my point.